# Run a JMH benchmark for gradle project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, jmh

Is there any direct way to run JMH benchmarks in eclipse for a gradle project.
I tried but faced issues like
No benchmarks to run (then copied manually the generated META-INF witch Mircobenchmark file in resources)

Then it gave generated.package_name.testClass class not found exception.Adding this to the build-path->source gives errors as it expects package name as gradle/classes/generated/package_name